# Selecting correct data from list view Android put extra

Tags: java, android, listview

I have code that sends data to another activity, but when I click on my item click listener I only get data from first item.

Here's code of fist activity's post execute:

```
  protected  void onPostExecute(JSONObject objdanejson){
        pDialog.dismiss();

        try {
            android = objdanejson.getJSONArray(TAG_ZAWARTOSC);
            for(int i = 0; i < android.length(); i++){
                JSONObject c = android.getJSONObject(i);

                final String akt_tytul = c.getString(TAG_TYTUL);
                String akt_skrot = c.getString(TAG_SKROT);
                final String akt_tresc = c.getString(TAG_TRESC);

                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                map.put(TAG_TYTUL, akt_tytul);
                map.put(TAG_SKROT, akt_skrot);

                Log.d(akt_tytul, "tytul");
                Log.d(akt_skrot, "skrot");
                Log.d(akt_tresc, "tresc");

                oslist.add(map);
                lista_aktualnosci = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lista_aktualnosci);

                final ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(aktualnosci.this, oslist,
                      R.layout.aktualnosc_item,
                        new String[]{TAG_TYTUL, TAG_SKROT}, new int[]{R.id.aktTytul, R.id.aktSkrot});
                lista_aktualnosci.setAdapter(adapter);

                lista_aktualnosci.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
                        @Override
                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                            Toast.makeText(aktualnosci.this, "Kliknąłeś na " + oslist.get(+position).get("nazwa"),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            Intent czytaj = new Intent(aktualnosci.this, aktualnosc_czytaj.class);
                            czytaj.putExtra("tytuł",akt_tytul);
                            czytaj.putExtra("tresc",akt_tresc);
                            startActivity(czytaj);
                        }
                });
```

and this is what I have in second activity:

```
package pl.webimpuls.wicms;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;
```

public class aktualnosc_czytaj extends AppCompatActivity {

```
  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_aktualnosc_czytaj);

        TextView aktczytaj_tytul = (TextView)    findViewById(R.id.aktczytaj_tytul);
        TextView aktczytaj_tresc = (TextView)     findViewById(R.id.aktczytaj_tresc);

        String czytajtytul;
        String czytajtresc;

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
            if(extras == null) {
                czytajtytul = null;
                czytajtresc = null;

                aktczytaj_tytul.setText(czytajtytul);
                aktczytaj_tresc.setText(czytajtresc);
            } else {
                czytajtytul = extras.getString("tytuł");
                czytajtresc = extras.getString("tresc");

                aktczytaj_tytul.setText(czytajtytul);
                aktczytaj_tresc.setText(czytajtresc);    
            }
        } else {
            czytajtytul = (String) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("tytuł");
            czytajtresc = (String) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("tresc");

            aktczytaj_tytul.setText(czytajtytul);
            aktczytaj_tresc.setText(czytajtresc);
        }
    }
}
```

How can I make it to show data from item that I click?

Comment: **Toast** displaying a write value?

Comment: That's temporary solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In second activity you should use Intent instead of Bundle:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
czytajtytul = intent.getStringExtra("tytuł");
czytajtresc = intent.getStringExtra("tresc");
```

Comment: Actually it shows null, no matter what I click. And I was wrong it only reads last one of items.

Comment: It reads only last item, because you are sending to activity last values of akt_tytul and akt_tresc:

    czytaj.putExtra("tytuł",akt_tytul);
    czytaj.putExtra("tresc",akt_tresc);

You should read those values from oslist for clicked position. 

And is there in your map key "nazwa"?

Comment: Thanks, you are great! And this was all in there.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing wrong. You don't use bundle if not passing bundle in intent.
You can get data by getIntent().getStringExtra(key).

Comment: Still not working as intended. It does show only data from first listview item.